# Facebook sdk - error: http status code 400

Tags: ios, facebook

So I'm trying to get facebook working with my new app, and I just cant figure this out.
I got every thing done like in the tutorial docs on their website. And when I start the app, I get a "Error: HTTP status code 400"; and nothing more to it.
I read all over the place that this is a serverside bug on facebook, but seriously? Some people have this working?

This is my code anyway:

```
FBSession* pFacebookSession = [[FBSession alloc] init];
[FBSession setActiveSession: pFacebookSession];
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
{        
     NSLog(@"openWithCompletionHandler start.");
     [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                FBSessionState status,
                                                                NSError *error)
                 {

                     NSLog(@"openWithCompletionHandler FINISHED!");
                 }];    


   }
```

not sure if this is what it is exactly to look like.

Comment: What tutorial did you follow, exactly?
Because the code from the official tutorial looks completely different.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/ try this tutorial its working in my app without any error